# Adventureworks exercises SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Using the SalesOrderHeader and SalesTerritory tables, write a query to calculate the number of transactions and
> total monthly amount per territory for each of the states based on the Status field. Status values ​​are:
> 1 = In process ; 2 = Approved ; 3 = Backordered ; 4 = Rejected ; 5 = Shipped ; 6 = Canceled
> The result table must contain the following fields:

1. Month : month in YYYY-MM format
2. NameTerritory : Name of the Territory
3. TrProcess : Transactions in process (Quantity)
4. TrApproved : Approved Transactions (Quantity)
5. TrBackordered : Overdue Transactions (Quantity)
6. TrRejected : Rejected Transactions (Quantity)
7. TrShipped : Transactions Sent (Amount)
8. TrCanceled : Transactions Canceled (Quantity)
9. MntProcess: Total amount in process
10. MntApproved: Total amount Approved
11. MntBackordered: Total Amount Arrears
12. MntRejected: Total Rejected amount
13. MntShipped: Total amount sent
14. MntCanceled: Total amount Canceled

[image]

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(A.ShipDate, 'yyyy-MM') as Mes,
    B.Name,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 1) as TrProcess,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 2) as TrApproved,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 3) as TrBackordered,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 4) as TrRejected,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 5) as TrShipped,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 6) as TrCanceled,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 1) as MntProcess,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 2) as MntApproved,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 3) as MntBackordered,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 4) as MntRejected,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 5) as MntShipped,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 6) as MntCanceled
FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader] A
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SalesTerritory] B on A.TerritoryID = B.TerritoryID
GROUP BY FORMAT(A.ShipDate,'yyyy/MM')
```

I have this query set up but I can't get my query to return the amounts.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Let's start by forgetting about the special formatting requirement and focus on getting correct data. First, don't use images to post important information. That should be consumable by including a script or fiddle - which will encourage others to help you. Next, you posted a query but make no mention of it. In fact, you ask no question. So - what is your question? If your query does not produce the required results, say that and say WHY it does not. While we're at it, add an ORDER BY clause to every query you write. Without, the rows have no particular order - a lesson to learn.

Comment: Ok I will try to improve, and I will improve the question posed, I am a beginner in sql and I will try to fix it

Comment: In adventureworks2012 (I don't have a later version) the tables belong to sales not dbo  You should also get Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'sales.SalesTerritory.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Your logic is flawed there is no correlation between the sub queries and the branch/date in th main query so they total everything. Read up on conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed there is no correlation between the sub queries and the branch/date in the main query so they total everything. Using conditional aggregation
demonstrates the difference

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(A.ShipDate, 'yyyy-MM') as mes,
    B.Name,
    (SELECT count(Status) FROM [sales].[SalesOrderHeader] where Status = 5) as TrProcess,
     sum(case when status = 5 then 1 else 0 end)  as trtprocesstrue

FROM [sales].[SalesOrderHeader] A
INNER JOIN [sales].[SalesTerritory] B on A.TerritoryID = B.TerritoryID
where b.name = 'northwest'
GROUP BY b.name,FORMAT(A.ShipDate, 'yyyy-MM') ;

mes        Name                                               TrProcess   trtprocesstrue
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------
2005-07    Northwest                                          31465       20
2005-08    Northwest                                          31465       28
2005-09    Northwest                                          31465       21
2005-10    Northwest                                          31465       22
```